# Who is more wealthy? Batman or IronMan

Tags: marvel, dc, batman, iron-man

I understand that they both from different universes but who has more wealth between the two?

Comment: I think they're both sufficiently wealthy that who has more is rather irrelevant.

Comment: I believe this falls under the [Shark Vs. Gorrilla](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) clause.

Comment: This isn't Shark vs. Gorilla - the question isn't "What's better, Iron Man or Batman?" but "Who is more wealthy?", and there is at least one "reputable" source with a clear answer.

Comment: What's the exchange rate between DC and Marvel currency?

Comment: Voted to leave closed, as it's written this is _far_ too broad - Iron Man and Batman's stories have been around for decades, they might have gotten poorer or richer, the question is just not narrow enough to begin phrasing an answer, methinks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best place for finding your answer is the article "[The Forbes Fictional 15](http://forbes.com/lists/fictional15/2011/forbes-fictional-15.html)".
In this top Bruce Wayne is on the 7th place with $7 Billion while Tony Stark is on the 5th place with $9.4 Billion. 
From my point of view if you watch the lifestyles of Tony Stark and Bruce Wayne, the first appears to be richer and to deserve it more for being a boy genius.

Comment: Here is the link with the Top: http://www.forbes.com/lists/fictional15/2011/forbes-fictional-15.html

Answer (score 1):

Tony Stark a.k.a IronMan is according to  Forbes Fictional 15 (see->http://www.forbes.com/lists/fictional15/2011/forbes-fictional-15.html)
wealthier than Bruce Wayne a.k.a Batman.
IronMan is on #6
Batman is on #8

PS: Depend on the exchange rate between the two universe. :p

Dont forget to vote!